# Should logging of heavy JSON data with logrus be launched in a separate goroutine?

Tags: go, logrus

I need to log relatively heavy JSON data within the web request handler. Does the logrus use blocking I/O?  Should I call the `logger.WithFields(fields).Info(heavy_message)` in a separate goroutine?

Comment: Is there a reason you have in mind to do so?

Comment: Well, I think if the logrus uses blocking I/O, the execution flow will be waiting until all data is sent to the buffer.

Comment: That's true, but I'm not sure why it's relevant - have you observed and measured a performance problem caused by logging?

Comment: "Does it use blocking I/O" is hardly an "opinion-based" question, bizarre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus/blob/79c5ab66aa2ce7d9ff7b3c437ebc22fcc519a967/entry.go#L221-L262
it looks like it is blocking i/o, so yes - you should call it in a goroutine.